# How to rewrite removed "forEachInvocation" jmockit?

Tags: testing, jmockit

I have to upgrade from jmockit v0.999.15 to jmockit v1.33 and I am having issues rewriting a test which is using "forEachInvocation"

```
request.addParam(anyString, anyString); minTimes = 1; maxTimes = 10; 
forEachInvocation = new Object() {
     void validate(String someName, String someValue) {
            if(Utils.XML.equals(someName)) {
                assertTrue("incorrect value",someValue.contains("This is a test")); 
            } 
     } 
};
```

The above piece of code is part of Expectations.

In jmockit website the following is mentioned, but I am not sure how to rewrite it:

"Version 1.7: Removed the **forEachInvocation** field, which was deprecated in release 1.6. Existing tests using it should instead take advantage of the **withCapture()** and withCapture(List) methods, or convert the handler object to a Delegate object assigned to the result field (in the case of a recorded expectation)."

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
List<String> someNames = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> someValues = new ArrayList<>();
request.addParam(withCapture(someNames), withCapture(someValues));minTimes = 1;maxTimes = 10;

for (String someName : someNames) {
    // assert some name as/if needed
}

for (String someValue; someValues) {
    // assert some values as/if needed
}
```